# PLC S7-1200 CPU 1211C Run/Stop LED is organge all time

Tags: plc, s7-1200, siemens, tia-portal

I'm having problems with my PLC s7-1200 CPU 1211C, after I connected to 24VDC LED status only turn on Run/Stop LED, but in orange colour, not Green, my PLC is new and I don't how to fix It.

Note: *I'm using TIA Portal V14 and also It doesn't recognized my PLC.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To setup your PLC in TIA-portal and follow the steps below:

1. add new device;
2. select your plc;
3. set up `ip address` and `device name` in the `PROFINET interface [X1]` in the `device view` properties;
4. if you click on `accessible devices` next to the `Go offline` button and search the the plc it should find it;
5. select the plc and press `show`;
6. This will bring you to `online access` of the device;
7. click on `online & diagnostics`;
8. If you expand, I think, the diagnostics tab you should be able to set the `ip address` and `device name` of the online device.

Now you should be able to download. The orange Rx/Tx LED will start blinking. When finished the Error LED is turned of and Run/Stop LED becomes green. Voila... your done.

Comment: Hi mrsargent, thank you, your solution works for me, the problem was the connection establishment, after I do load code the LED orange change to green and It works for me.